# In a Firebase Database Cloud Function, how can you add/replace an item in a list

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My database structure is:

```
- Scores
    - r5rwuerpepdsoazdf (user UID)
        - scoreString: "5,12"
    - j6fdasdfsdfs08fdd
        - scoreString: "1,4,7"
```

and I have a cloud function that updates the Score for a particular user UID when a value is written in another node (ScoreStacks):

```
exports.updateScoreString = 
functions.database.ref('/ScoreStacks/{uid}/{levelKey}/Score')
  .onWrite((dataSnapshot, context) => {
  const score = dataSnapshot.after.val();
  const scoreStringRef = dataSnapshot.after.ref.root.child('Scores/' + context.params.uid + '/scoreString');
  return scoreStringRef.transaction(scoreString => {
    if (!scoreString) // transactions return null first time
    {
      return scoreString;
    }
    return scoreStringWithAddedScore(scoreString, score);
  });
});
```

This is all working fine apart from if the UID in the Scores node does not yet exist. Then nothing happens.
I guess that is fair enough because scoreStringRef is refering to a path that doesn't exist.

So how can I ensure a new entry is made in the Scores node if the UID does not exist yet? It all has to be done atomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without seeing `scoreStringWithAddedScore`, but I suspect you want this:

```
  return scoreStringRef.transaction(scoreString => {
    if (!scoreString) // transactions return null first time
    {
      scoreString = "";
    }
    return scoreStringWithAddedScore(scoreString, score);
  });
```

A more concise (but somewhat harder to parse if you're new to this) version:

```
  return scoreStringRef.transaction(scoreString => {
    return scoreStringWithAddedScore(scoreString || "", score);
  });
```

Comment: scoreStringWithAddedScore appends the score to the existing scoreString. I tried returning "" when scoreString is null which does indeed create a new entry with the UID in Scores but with "" as the value and it doesn't get called again so never gets to the scoreStringWithAddedScore function. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ah, actually just calling scoreStringWithAddedScore (which already checks for null) does now work. So that's fixed it! (I had added the null check because I read somewhere if transactions return null you should just return null back.) Thanks for you help.